# Eclipse Export requires 'osgi.ee' could not be found

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, java-11

I tried to export my eclipse plugin projects in .products file. "Missing requirement: Eclipse Jobs Mechanism 3.12.0.v20210723-1034 requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))' but it could not be found .... " This error appears and I can't get a export.

Comment: `osgi.ee` just means the Execution Environment. The whole thing means Java 11 is required.

Comment: Note: You should be using [tag:tycho] with [tag:maven] for building plug-ins, the old Export mechanism is no longer maintaned. See [here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html)

Comment: Our execution environment already Java 11 but we get this error anyway. How to show that we use Java 11 or another way? We can start application in debug mode but during export we get this error. İt looks like that it requires 'osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))' where to show that?

Comment: Probably [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=568388). As I said you really need to be using [tag:tycho] for builds.